# In directional Circos plot with circlize, how to widen the end of ribbon?

Tags: r, circlize, circos

I am trying to widen the end of ribbon. Is it possible?

```
library(circlize)
mat2 = matrix(sample(100, 35), nrow = 5)
rownames(mat2) = letters[1:5]
colnames(mat2) = letters[1:7]
chordDiagram(mat2, grid.col = 1:7, directional = 1, row.col = 1:5)
```

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `target.prop.height` argument:

```r
chordDiagram(mat2, grid.col = 1:7, directional = 1, row.col = 1:5,
             target.prop.height = mm_h(1))
```

[image]

```r
chordDiagram(mat2, grid.col = 1:7, directional = 1, row.col = 1:5,
             target.prop.height = mm_h(3))
```

[image]